# Installing or building boost - Windows cannot access specified device, path, or file

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-build

I am try to get working boost with version **1_75_0-msvc-14.2-32** from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.75.0/ or build my own **1.75** boost version, but every time when I try to install it from link above, or try to open **b2.exe** to build my own version, I am getting error

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

The main problem is that I can not find any **log file** from witch I can know what is causing this problem, so does anyone know what I should do?

---

I was also trying to run some other versions of installer and found that **boost_1_75_0-msvc-14.1-64** version install without any problems, but this version is usless for me because I need **32x** version

The remaining **1.75** versions of installer that I tried and give me same error as above was - **11.0-32, 11.0-64, 14.1-32, 14.2-32**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, my antivirus was blocking some msvc files